# Maven: enabling resource filtering through the java api

Tags: maven, filtering, pom.xml, java, aether

I am using the standard java class MavenProject together with com.jcabi.aether.Aether java API to determine the set of jar dependencies for a give POM. There is no resource filtering occuring through the API by default and I'm yet to discover how to call Aether.resolve() for dependencies such as

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <version>${my-junit.version}</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

without getting DependencyResolutionException errors with 'cause: failed to load 'junit:junit:jar:${my-junit.version}' because it has the literal '${..}' version string. Here's a code snippet:

```
MavenProject proj = ..
Dependency dep = proj.getDependencies()...
Aether aether = new Aether(proj, ..)
aether.resolve(new DefaultArtifact(... dep.getVersion() ..)
```

How is it possible through these APIs to enable resource filtering so that user/built-in property substitution occurs by default? Or is this a manual process? Please provide code samples if possible, cheers!

Comment: Note that this isn't resource filtering, it's property interpolation. I would generate the full pom using `mvn help:effective-pom` and then have your code read in that.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem and had to do the property substitution manually. You can call the `getProperties()` method on your `MavenProject` reference.

Something along the following lines should work:

```
Properties props = proj.getProperties();
String depVersion = stripOutDollarAndCurlyBrackets(dep.getVersion());
String realDepVersion = props.getProperty(depVersion);
dep.setVersion(realDepVersion);
```

You obviously would need to write the `stripOutDollarAndCurlyBrackets()` method, but hopefully this gives you the idea.